# Iterate table rows in bigQuery

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

i am evaluating bigQuery. I have a table where i capture movement for our employees.

```
Table (location_history):

emp String
lat String
lng String
district String
timestamp timestamp
```

**Sample:**

```
emp  | lat     | lng    | district| timestamp
------------------------------------------------          
emp1 | 100.234 | 99.456 | ABC  | 2021-02-09 03:00:00
emp1 | 100.234 | 99.456 | XYZ  | 2021-02-09 04:00:00
emp1 | 100.234 | 99.456 | ABC  | 2021-02-09 05:00:00
emp1 | 100.234 | 99.456 | XYZ  | 2021-02-09 06:00:00
emp1 | 100.234 | 99.456 | XYZ  | 2021-02-09 07:00:00
emp1 | 100.234 | 99.456 | ABC  | 2021-02-09 08:00:00
emp1 | 100.234 | 99.456 | WWW  | 2021-02-09 09:00:00
```

**NOTE**: This is movement of each employee within districts. Employee can move from one district to another in no order other than timestamp. Moreover, there can be hundreds of repeated (same) rows even for one district as we capture every lng,lat (district is a polygon, superArea).

What i need is to track history for each employee visiting each district. So i can know which employee was in which district whole day. This can be a track for whole month. The rows (**each day**) we get in above table are more than 100 Billion.

**Two questions:**

1. Is it a good idea to process large number of rows in any Stored Procedure (regardless of any DB)? What is the performance factor in SP as compared to a language (server side like java, if fetching and inserting is neglected and just iterating or manipulating rows/resultSet is concerned)
2. Does BigQuery allow iteration over rows (from table using select statement)? And what would be the solution otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
Expected result is to calculate time spent by employee in each district. Flow will perform:

1. Query to get rows using (select * from location_history order by emp,district)
2. Then iterate over each row cox every other row is dependent on previous one to calculate the time spent in particular region

**Update 2:**
This should calculate duration for each employee separately (grouping them) and not calculating based on other employee activity. So, every first activity of each employee would have null/zero duration and if next activity found will do calculation from previous row. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a result (table, report, etc.) you would to get from the  example of the source data you provided, please?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand how stored procedures correlate to your goals. Why, what for, do you need it?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over rows?

Comment: If the table is big - can you consider partitioned https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables and clustered https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables tables?

Comment: @al-dann Thanks for response. Actually i corelate SP over external language cox i was wondering about the iterating speed which a language can provide vs SP iteration. Plus what should be the accurate solution for such sequential calculations. I have updated my question tho

Comment: Based on the provided update - I would guess that SQL capabilities (including analytics functions) should be enough to get the answer. Not sure you need to iterate or do anything else. Just develop a correct/accurate SQL query and run it either from UI or from scheduler or from an external functional component (ie.e. cloud function).

Comment: @al-dann how this sequential query can be written. Can you please write that out. I moved to row by row because i was unable to produce a query for this. Thanks

Comment: I cannot write instead of you (at least at this moment)... I would suggest using aggregate SQL functions and/or analytical SQL functions https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts - using them you can find the start time and the end time in a particular area, thus the duration... Using subqueries https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries#example_tables - you can 'join' the calculation into one query, which can be executed/scheduled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select emp, district, date,
  datetime_diff(
    date, 
    lag(date) over(partition by emp order by date), 
    minute
  ) minutes_in_district
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

I assumed your date column is of DATETIME data type
In case if it is TIMESTAMP data type - you should use timestamp_diff function instead of datetime_diff

Comment: can you refer any good resources on learning these tough concepts for bigQuery like partition, windowing, analytic functions etc?

Comment: how to perform above calculation for each employee?? so that every first occurrence of each employee would be null and then starts calculating afterwards. No mixing of times of other employees

Comment: it is already working this way - because of `partition by emp` part

Answer (score 0):

you can't compare the stored procedure of all DB engine. Each one has their characteristics. Anyway, for big query, processing a large volume of data isn't a problem, as long as you have money to pay for this!

About the processing by a language, it's a matter of opinion. For me, if you are an hardcore developer and you manage all the optimization tricks, you can build something as efficient as built in databases. DB Engine are optimized to process efficiently set of data, to sort them, to index them (...). In addition, staying in the DB, you don't loose network time to export data to another system to perform the processing.

As Google said me "If you can describe your manipulation data in SQL, BigQuery will be always faster and cheaper than others, such as Dataflow or Dataproc". However, BigQuery can't perform external API call. If it's your use case, you need process data outside BigQuery

About the 2nd point, BigQuery proposes [Analytics function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts) and I think that you are look for this. If you need help to build the request, can you provide a sample of the expected result?

---

**EDIT 1**

If you try this query (with your sample data for test)

```
with data as (
select "emp1" as emp, 100.234 as log, 99.456 as lat, "ABC" as district, ("2021-02-09 03:00:00") as date 
UNION ALL
select "emp1" as emp, 100.234 as log, 99.456 as lat, "XYZ" as district, ("2021-02-09 04:00:00") as date 
UNION ALL
select "emp1" as emp, 100.234 as log, 99.456 as lat, "ABC" as district, ("2021-02-09 05:00:00") as date 
UNION ALL
select "emp1" as emp, 100.234 as log, 99.456 as lat, "XYZ" as district, ("2021-02-09 06:00:00") as date 
UNION ALL
select "emp1" as emp, 100.234 as log, 99.456 as lat, "XYZ" as district, ("2021-02-09 07:00:00") as date 
UNION ALL
select "emp1" as emp, 100.234 as log, 99.456 as lat, "ABC" as district, ("2021-02-09 08:00:00") as date 
UNION ALL
select "emp1" as emp, 100.234 as log, 99.456 as lat, "WWW" as district, ("2021-02-09 09:00:00") as date
)
select emp, date, district as current_distinct, LAG(district) over (ORDER by date) as prev_district from data
```

You can get this result:

```
emp     date                    current_distinct    prev_district
emp1    2021-02-09 03:00:00     ABC 
emp1    2021-02-09 04:00:00     XYZ                  ABC
emp1    2021-02-09 05:00:00     ABC                  XYZ
emp1    2021-02-09 06:00:00     XYZ                  ABC
emp1    2021-02-09 07:00:00     XYZ                  XYZ
emp1    2021-02-09 08:00:00     ABC                  XYZ
emp1    2021-02-09 09:00:00     WWW                  ABC
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually my scenario is to iterate over rows and each row depends on previous row of employee to see how much time he spent in particular district. For that i was wondering if i should write a SP or simple JDBC (batch) to process each row.

Comment: Is my edit helps you? is it what you expect?

Comment: There can be thousand districts

Comment: And? What do you want to achieve? What do you expect at the end?